# GRASS plugin to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis-2.0, qgis-grass-plugin

I want to work on QGIS using GRASS HRU. it needs QGIS software to boot first, but it is not booting. I tried reinstalling the software also. I can open GRASS but its not giving any result. 
I installed QGIS. GRASS plugin is already there. it is taking input but not giving any output. in manual it was written that when you will open QGIS it will boot. but what I have is not booting. I have QGIS in ILMS software.  `what can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: give more infos. QGIS version, GRASS version, Operating System? I have a similar issue right now on Ubuntu xenial with QGIS 2.18